# Dell PowerEdge 750

Tags: rack, dell-poweredge, physical-environment

Can I use Dell PowerEdge 750 just 1U without a rack at home? Does it need cooling?

I want to have a low end server for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had one sitting on a shelf for 2 years worked fine.

Comment: Is it noisy?  I had an old DL380 that roared like a jet plane when I turned it on.

Comment: @Mitch Proliabts usually need the PSP installed to properly control the fan speed.  More work than it needs to be if you're not on a rpm-based OS.  Why HP doesn't do it in firmware is beyond me...

Comment: I guess, Dell PowerEdge 750 should be fine then ?

Comment: Rackmount servers don't **need** a rack to be used, but it will help with airflow. Most servers and computers have enough cooling internally anyway, so as long as you don't block the air inlets/outlets, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The 750 will work just fine without a rack.  Rack mount servers suck air in from the front and blow it through out the back - not out the top or sides like desktops.  As long as these areas are clear, put it wherever!